# Is there anyway in marklogic to get all the content in one go

Tags: marklogic

Can all the contents from Marklogic database(Content Database) extracted in one go? Does ML provide any out of box solutions like that. I read about mlcp. That looked like a command line utility to me. What I want is a function which can be included as an xquery in modules DB.

Comment: mlcp is a command line utility, yes, written in Java though and MarkLogic does provide it as Open Source should you desire to re-use in some way.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.marklogic.com/fn:collection will return the entire database, if that is what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "extracted" ... that is how do you want the results ? One big concatenated file ? A directory tree ? A Zip File?
Also realize that for anything but fairly small database sizes you will have to do this incrementally because the entire DB cannot be stored in memory.

Places to look for ways to accomplish this are

https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:zip-create

You can create a single ZIP file of all documents then store it to the filesystem with

https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:save
This will only work if you can hold the entire database in memory.

Or you can iterate over all documents and save them one by one with xdmp:save

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there are no out of the box export solutions included in the distribution of MarkLogic, other than mlcp, and things like backup. It would have been nice if there were something like Information Studio, but for export instead of import.

However you will have all ingredients available that you need, and you can write some code that does this for you relatively easy. The basic steps you usually take for this are:

- identify the docs you want, preferably get their uris through URI lexicon
- chunk this list into pieces of lets say 100 docs
- spawn a sub task for each chunk that reads the docs from database, and writes them to disk using functions like xdmp:zip-create and xdmp:save as @daldei suggests.
- perhaps have main and sub-tasks write some stats to the database. The info: and infodev: libraries provide functionality to work with 'tickets', usefull for that purpose.

HTH!